# How to handle different types of dates in a column in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to find different data types in a column of pandas dataFrame and have them in a separate column for some computation. I have tried Regex with mask function to identify other data types like string and integer as shown below

```
df[data_types]=df[i].astype(str).str.contains('^[-+]?[0-9]+$', case=False, regex=True), "Integer").mask(df[i].astype(str).str.contains('^[a-zA-Z ]+$', case=False, regex=True), "string")
```

Here the problem is i want to handle  different types of date formats and identify them as a single data type "date". And column may have any type of data as below :

```
column_1
----------
18/01/18
01/18/18
17/01/2018
12/21/2018
jan-02-18
Nan
02-jan-18
2018/01/13
hello
2345
```

EDIT :
I have used mask in same line because, i want to handle every datatype in the column and identify them to have a final result like below

```
     column_1  |  data_types
    ---------- |- - - - - - - 
    18/01/18   | date
    01/18/18   | date
    17/01/2018 | date
    12/21/2018 | date
    jan-02-18  | date
    Nan        | null
    02-jan-18  | date
    2018/01/13 | date
    hello      | string
    2345       | Integer
```

and this gives exactly what i need

```
df[data_types]=df[i].astype(str).str.contains('^[-+]?[0-9]+$', case=False, regex=True), "Integer").mask(df[i].astype(str).str.contains('^[a-zA-Z ]+$', case=False,regex=True),string").mask(to_datetime(df[i],errors='coerce').notnull(),"date".mask(df[i].astype(str).str.contains('nan', case=False, regex=True), "null")
```

Any help provided is highly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) for create new column by multiple condition and for datetimes use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) with `errors='coerce'` for return `NaN`s for not parseable values, so check it by [`notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.notna.html):

```
m1 = df[i].astype(str).str.contains('^[-+]?[0-9]+$', case=False, regex=True)
m2 = df[i].astype(str).str.contains('^[a-zA-Z ]+$', case=False, regex=True)

m3 = pd.to_datetime(df[i], errors='coerce').notna()
#oldier pandas versions
#m3 = pd.to_datetime(df[i], errors='coerce').notnull()

df[data_types]= np.select([m1, m2, m3], ["Integer", 'string', 'date'], default='not_matched')
```

Comment: Thank you !! this gave the exact spark that i needed

Comment: @Harish - No problem use `.mask`, but one thing - I suggest create each mask for separate line for better readable code ;)